# How can I fix this 'Not Found' error when I run my web application?

Tags: python, html, web-applications, pycharm

I'm making a web application, but when I run it on localhost, and when I press the 'zoek' (search) button it should display the results.html page, but I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? It should display some text. I'm using PyCharm.

This is the project:
https://github.com/YoniTi/Project8

EDIT: On one laptop it works fine, on another it doesn't...

Comment: with the same browser i assume ? maybe check the version of installed packages, flask ...